# QUERY with "contains" and "date range"

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am trying to write a formula that would pull data based on a selection I made and within the date range I put in as well. The code I wrote below does not work. What am I writing incorrectly?!

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A2,"!A:FB")), "where (C >=date '"&TEXT('Feedback Report'!C3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C <= date '"&TEXT('Feedback Report'!D3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E contains '"&B2&"' ",1)
```

Comment: You may want to tag with the software or language you are using. `formula` is pretty generic.

Comment: Thank you teylyn. Just added Google Spreadsheet tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked too soon. After trying one more time, I have found a solution:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A2,"!A:FB")), "Select * where (C >=date '"&TEXT('Feedback Report'!C3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C <= date '"&TEXT('Feedback Report'!D3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E contains'"&B2&"')")
```

Here is the breakdown:

- Formula is on a sheet that pulls data from another source (raw data)
- INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A2,"!A:FB")) is where the data is stored
- A2 is the sheet I choose from a drop down menu to have the data be pulled from
- C is the date column of the raw data
- C3 is the starting query date
- D3 is the ending query date
- E is the category column
- B2 is the category value I want to search on

Hope this helps people in the future.